# Oracle Dependencies exists error

Tags: sql, oracle

When I try to disable the constraint I am getting the following error

> cannot disable constraint (SCOTT.EMPLOYEE_PK) - dependencies exist

Please give me the solution for this problem.

Can I use `CASCADE` to disable the constraint?

If I use `CASCADE`, then will I able to enable the constraint again?

Comment: What code are you using? Did you try `cascade`?

Comment: alter table employee disable constraint SCOTT.EMPLOYEE_PK ;

Comment: alter table employee disable constraint SCOTT.EMPLOYEE_PK cascade; both i have tried

Comment: My doubt is will i able to enable the constraint after disbaling using cascade

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14219/e2100.htm#sthref1353) the action to do is:

> Either disable the foreign key constraints or use disable cascade

So use this to disable the primary key and its index:

```
alter table employee disable primary key
```

You can re-enable the index/constraint when done, but make sure you don't invalidate the index:

```
alter table employee enable primary key
```

Also read: [Modifying, Renaming, or Dropping Existing Integrity Constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general005.htm#ADMIN11546).

Comment: can you give me example for foreign key also like this

Comment: I would suggest to read the documentation in the link since it covers it all.

Comment: I have disable the constraint using cascade after that i have enabled the constraint but it is not showing any error like before even though dependecies are exists

Comment: alter table testing disable constraint empno_pk cascade ;                      alter table testing enable constraint empno_pk;

Comment: empno_pk is fk in testing1 table after enable i have inserter the row in testing1 but as per the dependencies it wont allow to insert the values which are not present in primary table right

Comment: Can you give the full create statements for your tables and constraints?